# If jailbreak is for iPhone then what is it for MacBook?

Tags: macos, ios, jailbreak

As we know we can jailbreak any iOS device to loosen the OS rules.

1 Is there anything similar to macOS devices also?
2 If Yes, then what is it?
3 Is it possible to do it from remote?
4 How can I do for preventing my MacBook from getting jailbroken?

Comment: Any comment would be welcomed saying why down voted

Comment: Up voted as it is a legit question by someone who doesn't know. If someone searches for this and finds this question, it won't get reasked.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for subjective questions. You've basically asked a "yes/no" question. No one can guess why you're asking, what you're trying to learn or what you are trying to do. basically, it's not showing a practical problem to be solved and seems more discussion oriented.

Comment: @bmike: updated question body.

Comment: Jailbreaking is something you do to overcome Apple's access restrictions on your own device.  There is no need to do it on a Mac, since there are no such restrictions.  Are you now asking how to prevent yourself from having complete access to your Mac?  Or are you really just asking how to prevent yourself from being hacked?  That topic has already been covered in great detail in a lot of places......

Comment: There is no such thing as a jailbreak for macOS, so the question as asked is kind of unanswerable. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve or prevent here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to. Administrator account is available. That is basically what you want with "jailbreak" on iOS.

EDIT: NoahL has a point about disabling SIP, forgot about that one. More info here http://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: True, but System Integrity Protection protects system files. So to truly "jailbreak" macOS, you would need to disable SIP.